# Error while going into designer layout for android aplication using vs2015

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.android

I have created a android application in visual studio 2015
when i go into layout and open Main.axml 
I will get the following error.

Sometimes this error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Strangers_Call\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesigner3364567969202547439.dll: 
Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at mono.android.JniHelper.loadEmbeddedJniLibrary(JniHelper.java:28)
    at mono.android.D3DImageFactory.<clinit>(D3DImageFactory.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
    at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
    at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

And sometimes this one

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Users\Strangers_Call\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesigner3364567969202547439.dll: 
Can't load AMD 64-bit .dll on a IA 32-bit platform
    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1941)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1824)
    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:809)
    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1086)
    at mono.android.JniHelper.loadEmbeddedJniLibrary(JniHelper.java:28)
    at mono.android.D3DImageFactory.<clinit>(D3DImageFactory.java:14)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.initializePlatformSpecific(DesignerSession.java:86)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.<init>(DesignerSession.java:75)
    at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:382)
    at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue??

Comment: There is a requirement of having JDK 1.8 x64 bit installed. This error message is saying you only have x32 bit installed. https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/vs/xamarin.vs_4/xamarin.vs_4.2/#XVS_4.2.0.680

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> UnsatisfiedLinkError is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find
>   an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

`C:\Users\Strangers_Call\AppData\Local\Temp\AndroidDesigner3364567969202547439.dll` file in your case appears to be 64-bit whereas your system runs on 32-bit. Hence, the system can not load this file and you are getting the error.